# IE not implemented javascript error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using some basic jQuery at http://s329880999.onlinehome.us/ and I'm getting a "not implemented" error in Internet Explorer. I'm guessing that this is to do with my using top (var s2). How can I make it work in IE?

Comment: Would you mind posting a *non-minified* version of your JS?

Comment: @Matti - Just take the `-min` out of the URL :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

currently you have:

```
window.onload=imageRotate();
```

This will execute the function immediately, assigning `undefined` (the *result* of `imageRotate()`) to the `onload` handler...what you actually want is to reference the function here, like this:

```
window.onload=imageRotate;
```